# How to retrieve column name from table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have created a database from which I want to retrieve the names of the desired columns from a particular table.How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

you could try below options , assuming you are trying from command line

```
DESCRIBE your_table ;
```

or you could

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table;
```